# Is there a standard/recommended syntax for defining a keyboard binding?

Tags: key-bindings, syntax

I have seen all of the following for defining a keyboard binding.  All of these work (at least on MS Windows). I don't know if there is another way to do the same thing.
I am wondering if there is a standard or recommended way to define a keyboard binding and if it is recommended to avoid some of these.

```
(global-set-key "\M-r" 'some-command)
(global-set-key [(meta r)] 'some-command)
(global-set-key [?\M-r] 'some-command)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-r") 'some-command)
```

Comment: I doubt there is a recommended syntax but I personally like the `(global-set-key (kbd "M-r") 'some-command)` method because of the consistency in which the key combinations can be defined.. you don't have to remember when or when not to escape stuff.

Answer (score 6):

There is no single standard way, because there are different use cases.

If you are writing such code manually, in your init file for example, then you might prefer the `(kbd ...)` format, because the argument to `kbd` uses the same notation that Emacs uses when it communicates with you about key bindings (in `*Help*`, for example).

But if you are creating bindings using Emacs Lisp, then you might prefer the vector notation, in particular `[(meta r)]` etc., as it is quite a bit easier to manage.

Some people consider the simple string approach to be archaic, but it is handy when the key is simple: `"a"` is simpler and at least as readable as `(kbd "a")`.  But simple strings are harder to read/use when it comes to modifier keys etc.

Answer (score 6):

```
(global-set-key [?\M-r] 'some-command)
```

is the "native" way.  All others are built on top of this one, basically.