# is there a canonical way of representing key combinations in elisp? what is it?

Tags: key-bindings

I've seen many different ways of specifying key combinations for setting or unsetting key bindings in emacs.  Some are quoted, others are bracketed, some are escaped, others are not.  Do they all work in all contexts?  Is there a best practice?

Some examples from my init file which may or may not work:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-right>") nil)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-k") (foo))
(define-key global-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
(global-set-key [(C-f4)] 'bury-buffer)
(global-set-key [(f6)] 'emms-playlist-mode-go)
(define-key c-mode-map  [(tab)] 'company-complete)
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g s") 'ggtags-find-other-symbol)
(setq helm-gtags-prefix-key "\C-cg")
(define-key evil-normal-state-map [escape] 'keyboard-quit)
(bind-key "<escape>" 'isearch-cancel isearch-mode-map)
(global-unset-key "\M-:")
```

Is there a canonical way to define key combinations?  If so, where can I read about it, especially for a list of special and modifier keys (tab, escape, return, meta, ctrl, shift, super, Fn, delete)?

edit: This question and the answers below go a lot deeper than the similar question [asked here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14992/is-there-a-standard-recommended-syntax-for-defining-a-keyboard-binding).

Comment: For additional examples, have a look at the built-in source code located at `.../lisp/bindings.el` and `.../lisp/term/ns-win.el` (for OSX).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard/recommended syntax for defining a keyboard binding?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14992/is-there-a-standard-recommended-syntax-for-defining-a-keyboard-binding)

Comment: All I can tell you is that `[(C-f4)]` is the obsolete way or as the sources put it, "Lucid-style event type list".  Personally, I'd always use the `kbd` syntax unless there's something you can't easily represent with it, then you can go for either strings or vectors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The internal representation of a key sequence is as a vector of [events](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Events.html#Input-Events). The internal representation is anything that the built-in primitives `define-key` and `lookup-key` recognize, and all the other functions based on them.

An individual event can be a character (for characters, possibly with modifiers), a symbol (for any event, possibly with modifiers) or a list (containing modifiers and a base event). There can be more than one representation of an event, e.g. `(meta ?a)` and `?\M-a` are the same event. I don't think that there is one representation of events that is officially declared canonical.

If you want to compare events (but you probably don't, because input processing is complicated — let the keymap code handle that), you can call [`event-modifiers`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Classifying-Events.html#index-event_002dmodifiers) and [`event-basic-type`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Classifying-Events.html#index-event_002dbasic_002dtype) to decompose an event, or contrariwise [`event-convert-list`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Classifying-Events.html#index-event_002dconvert_002dlist) to pack the event into a single symbol.

The [`kbd`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html#index-kbd) function turns a “human-friendly” key sequence representation into an internal event representation.

When defining a keymap, use whatever syntax you prefer.

There are some events that are normally mapped to the same binding, via [translation keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#Translation-Keymaps). If you're defining a package, you should steer away from those translation keymaps; these are to some extent terminal-dependent and to some extent a user preference. Here a few things to be aware of:

- Some function keys are mapped to a control character:

  - `[escape]` → `(kbd "ESC")` = `?\e` = `?\C-\[`
  - `[return]` → `(kbd "RET")` = `?\r` = `?\C-m` (and `[linefeed]` to `?\C-j` but few keyboards have that)
  - `[tab]` → `(kbd "TAB")` = `?\t` = `?\C-i`
  - `[backspace]` → `(kbd "DEL")` = `?\C-?` (with additional complications relating to `?\C-h` that I won't go into)

  Don't define bindings for those function keys, define bindings for the corresponding character instead.
- `ESC` is very special. `ESC key` is normally equivalent to `(meta key)`. On text terminals, most function keys are mapped to character sequences that start with `ESC`. So never define a binding for `ESC`.
- A mouse click has the mouse button going down, then up, with the mouse possibly moving in between. This generates a flurry of different events. In addition rapid repeated clicks (double click, etc.) are recognized as such. See [Mouse Events](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mouse-Events.html#Mouse-Events) and subsequent sections in the manual.

Comment: "never define a binding for `ESC`" seems incompatible with evil-mode, whose rising popularity can't be ignored.  Notice my binding `(global-unset-key "\M-:")` is to prevent the fast sequence `ESC : w RET` from trying to interpret `w` as lisp instead of saving the buffer.

Comment: Evil uses elaborate hacks with great care to allow doing this without messing with keybindings involving meta.  Point is if you naïvely define a binding to `ESC`, this breaks meta.

Comment: @AlejandroErickson I meant that for “ordinary” modes and “normal” users. Evil isn't an ordinary mode, it essentially takes over the whole interface.

Comment: ok thanks.  I was just clarifying, not accusing :)

Answer (score 7):

1. There is no "canonical" representation.
2. If you want an external, i.e., source-code representation that is applicable generally and easy to read, then use **`kbd`**. The manual and `C-h k` will tell you the external representation for a given key, and you can pass that to `kbd` in a string.  The value returned is an internal representation of the key sequence.  Similarly, you can use function **`key-description`** as an approximate inverse of `kbd`.

   For example, in the example you gave of using `[(C-f4)]` you could just as easily used the external representation `C-<f4>`, wrapping that as a string with `kbd`: `(kbd "C-<f4")` -- that returns `[C-f4]` which is equivalent to `[(C-f4)]`.
3. To see how a given key binding might be represented internally, you can also examine a keymap where it is bound (using, for example, `C-h v` with a keymap variable, such as `ctl-x-map`).

The doc for `kbd` tells you:

> This function converts the text KEYSEQ-TEXT (a string constant)
>        into a key sequence (a string or vector constant).  The contents of
>        KEYSEQ-TEXT should use the same syntax as in the buffer invoked by
>        the `C-x C-k <RET>` (`kmacro-edit-macro`) command; in particular,
>        you must surround function key names with `<…>`. See [(emacs)Edit
>        Keyboard Macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Edit-Keyboard-Macro.html).

See the Emacs manual, node [Key Bindings](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html) and its subnodes, and the Elisp manual, node [Keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymaps.html) and its subnodes.